# how to get source file from apk file

Tags: android, android-install-apk

in android there is any possibility to getting source file from .apk file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Getting source code from an APK file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You need a decompiler for that. But be careful to consider the legal issues.

I use [Dedexer](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/) or [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/). Most times there are good results, but sometimes it is not possible to decompile all sources.

Answer (score 1):

Well, normally you can't or shouldn't be able to, but you can try to 'reverse engineer' the apk (as its called) by using android-apktool:

http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

I have no experience with the program yet by the way

Answer (score 0):

just go to this tutorial

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1108798
i hope it will help u.